# how to add header row to df.to_csv output file only after a certain condition is met

Tags: pandas, ta-lib

I am reading a bulk download csv file of Stock prices and splitting it into many individual csv's based on ticker, where ticker name is the name of the outputted file and where the header row which contains "ticker, date, open, high, low, close, volume is being written ONLY the the first time I run the script because if I run it again with the header set to true, it writes a new header row mixed in with the stock data. I have mode set to "a", meaning "append" because I want each new row of data added to the file. However, I see a situation now where a new ticker has appeared in the source file, and  because I have the header set to False, there is no header in this newly created output file, which causes processing to fail. How can I include a condition so that it writes a header row ONLY for new files which never existed  before. Here is my code. Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv
import itertools
import datetime

datetime = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

filename = "Bats_"+(datetime)+".csv"

csv_file = ("H:\\EOD_DATA_RECENT\\DOWNLOADS\\"+filename)

path = 'H:\\EOD_DATA_RECENT\\VIA-API-CALL\\BATS\\'

df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

for i, g in df.groupby('Ticker'):

    # SET HEADER TO TRUE THE FIRST RUN, THEN SET TO FALSE THEREAFTER
    g.to_csv(path + '{}.csv'.format(i), mode='a', header=False, index=False, index_label=None)
    print(df.tail(5))
```

FINAL CODE SNIPPET BELOW THAT WORKS. Thanks

```
for i, g in df.groupby('Ticker'):
   
    if os.path.exists(path+i+".csv"):
        g.to_csv(path + '{}.csv'.format(i), mode='a', header=False, index=False, index_label=None)
    else:
        g.to_csv(path + '{}.csv'.format(i), mode='w', header=True,    index=False, index_label=None)
        print(df.tail(5))
```

Comment: use `os.path.exists(file)` as a condition to check if it needs to add column header.